# Unable to insert the values into a table

Tags: c#, sql-server

I am inserting values into a table and below is my code

```
 protected void Button4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string conn = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["mineConnection"].ConnectionString;
        SqlConnection conn1=new SqlConnection(conn);
        conn1.Open();
       SqlCommand cmd1=new SqlCommand("insert into emp values(@empid,@name)",conn1);
      cmd1.Parameters.Add("@empid", TextBox11.Text);
      cmd1.Parameters.Add("@name", TextBox12.Text);
        SqlDataReader dr;
        SqlCommand cmd=new SqlCommand("select * from emp where empid='"+TextBox11.Text+"'",conn1);
        dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        if(dr.HasRows)
        {
         if(dr.Read())
         {
           if(TextBox11.Text==dr[0].ToString())
           {
             Response.Write("id already exists");
           }
         }

        }
        else
        {
          dr.Close();
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            Response.Write("values inserted");
        }
  }
    }
```

but the problem is i am unable to insert the values and i am not getting any error also.Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Because you are not executing SqlCommand `cmd1` anywhere in your code.

After defining the command

```
  SqlCommand cmd1=new SqlCommand("insert into emp values(@empid,@name)",conn1);
  cmd1.Parameters.Add("@empid", TextBox11.Text);
  cmd1.Parameters.Add("@name", TextBox12.Text);
```

Execute the query

```
cmd1.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Comment: oops i missed that now it worked :).

Comment: How can i use the same above code to pass parameters like creating a method and passing the values?

Comment: Select the code, right click on it, select Refactor -> Extract Method, this will give you an idea

Comment: when i use Refractor->Extract for the above code the return value is greyed out and i cant declare the parameters also how to get the return value get working??

Answer (score 2):

I do not see the line in your code, where you actually execute the insert command.

You definde the cmd1 command, but never used it, so you do not insert the data because of that.